# Bayesian Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian

I am trying to fit a model that has multiple parameters to experimental data. I can do this pretty easily only considering one parameter, but when I have multiple, I am having trouble. Here is my code:

```py
def model_a(x,params):
    y = params[0] + x*params[1] + params[2]*x**2

    return y

def model_b(x,params):
    y = params[0]*(np.exp(-0.5*(x-params[1])**2/params[2]**2))

    return y

def log_likelihood(x,y,sigma,params,bool_mod):

    log_like = np.zeros(len(params[0]))

    if bool_mod == True:
        for xx,yy,ss in zip(x,y,sigma):
            log_like += -0.5*((((model_a(xx,params))-yy)**2)/(ss**2))

    else:
        for xx,yy,ss in zip(x,y,sigma):
            log_like += -0.5*((((model_b(xx,params))-yy)**2)/(ss**2))

    return log_like

def post(x,y,sigma,bool_mod,n):
    params = [np.random.uniform(-2,2,n),np.random.uniform(-20,30,n),np.random.uniform(0,1,n)]
    log_like = log_likelihood(x,y,sigma,params,bool_mod)
    norm = np.trapz(log_like,params)

    return params, log_like, norm

params, log_like, norm = post(x,y,sigma_y,True,1000)

best_index = np.argmax(log_like)

print(params[0][best_index],params[1][best_index],params[2][best_index])
```

So, I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach a multiple variable regression. Mainly, I'm having doubts whether I should define my parameters as random numbers.

Comment: ...so what is the problem?

Comment: Mainly, I'm having doubts whether I should define my parameters as random numbers.